# Add an annotation with "add" command in Taskwarrior

Tags: taskwarrior

Can I add an annotation to a task in Taskwarrior while creating it like that?

```
task add Description annotation:Anno
```

Normaly I have to do it with two commands

```
task add Description
task 1 annotate Anno
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible with the add command as the [documentation](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/commands/add.html) states:

> You cannot add annotations while creating a task because it interferes with the task description.

A possible workaround would be a script asking for the annotation:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

task add $@
ID=$(task +LATEST ids)
read -p "Annotation: " ANNOTATION
task $ID annotate $ANNOTATION
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating an alias is an alternative to the mentioned script . For example:

```bash
alias tann='task annotate "$(task +LATEST uuids)"'
```

Note that this only allows to annotate the last added task.

You would use it like this:

```bash
task add 'My task'
tann 'My annotation'
```